# Cloud Scheduler, scheduling Cloud Function via Pub/Sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a GCP Cloud Function that is triggered by a message on Pub/Sub topic. To schedule this function, I am using Cloud Scheduler who's target is the same Pub/Sub topic that triggers the Cloud Function.

I am giving the cloud scheduler service account `service-<project_number>@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com` Pub/Sub Admin on the target Pub/Sub topic. In spite of this, I am getting the following error in the scheduler.

```
{
  insertId: "1snh9yyg2l3mb0r"
  jsonPayload: {
    @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
    jobName: "projects/<project_id>/locations/<region>/jobs/fsi-token-as- 
    secret-schedule"
    pubsubTopic: "projects/<project_id>/topics/fsi"
    status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    targetType: "PUB_SUB"
  }
  logName: "projects/<p_id>/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
  receiveTimestamp: "2021-09-17T09:01:52.949186058Z"
  resource: {
     labels: {3}
     type: "cloud_scheduler_job"
  }
  severity: "ERROR"
  timestamp: "2021-09-17T09:01:52.949186058Z"
}
```

What configuration am I missing? I have seen other examples on stack overflow but they all reference a HTTP trigger and not a Pub/Sub trigger.

Comment: PERMISSION_DENIED is your error..maybe you need to look at your IAM/Roles

Comment: Yes, if I am not mistaken, it is the service account service-<project_number>@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com that is responsible for writing to the Pub/Sub topic. As I mentioned, I made this SA Pub/Sub admin of the given topic.

Comment: Is the topic in the same project as the Cloud Scheduler?